# How can I use MS Web Test to upload files to SharePoint?

Tags: 2007

I created a web test to upload a file to SharePoint and also made sure that the file that I upload while recording gets deployed to my test out folder by following this article: [How to upload a file in a Web test](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/edglas/how-to-upload-a-file-in-a-web-test)

My test runs successfully but doesn't upload the file to the SharePoint document library.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a series of generic tests that can be used to upload documents to a SharePoint 2007 document library at 
[SharePoint Performance Tests-Codeplex](http://spperformancetest.codeplex.com/). To get this to work you just need to put in the URL to the site and the details of the document library(s) you want to upload to. Let me know if you have any problems getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

which user make the upload ?

are you sure they are not just simply in check-out ? making them not visible for any other users?